# TikZ plots samples count — the more, the better?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I plot a lot of spirals like this one:

```
\draw[domain=0:2*pi, variable=\t, samples=500]
    plot[fixed point arithmetic] 
    (1.2*exp(0.22*\t)*cos(deg(\t))}, {1.2*exp(0.22*\t)*sin(deg(\t))});
```

with TikZ and use for final renders as much samples as possible (~5000 or more).
Are there any cons of doing so? 
Output PDF-file size (~150 Kb instead of ~6 Kb) doesn't count.
The images I need are ~50x50 mm in general.

Comment: No cons except memory. Pros: better curve.

Comment: @HarishKumar And time. But there must be some limit to the pros, especially given the limitations of TeX in terms of precision and of the human eye, for that matter. Beyond a certain point, it will surely be nothing but cons, even if the cons are of minor concern.

Comment: There is no pros for 5x5 plots either. It's a PDF so nothing will make sense beyond the psychological limit of the readers. It's a spiral. And that's about it

Comment: These 5x5 cm plots are for a reissue of a math book so the illustrations have to be as precise as possible. The rendering time is not a con as well in this case.